# How to tag Button to ViewHolder created in custom adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

i am using custom adapter with each row having number of buttons created using,

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View rowview = (HorizontalScrollView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.hrowlayout, parent, false);
LinearLayout ll1 = (LinearLayout) rowview.findViewById(R.id.ll);    
Button[] b = new Button[M];     
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        b[i] = new Button(ll1.getContext());
        b[i].setText(....);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( x, 90);
        b[i].setLayoutParams(param2);
        ll1.addView(b[i],params2);
        }
 return rowview;   
}
```

My question is how to use ViewHolder on this adapter and how to tag the buttons which are not in XML file .. i.e on

```
b[i] = new Button[M];
```

Comment: where is your view holder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ViewHolder in the ViewHolder pattern is a dumb object that just holds a reference to the contents of a view to avoid repetitive use of inflate() and findViewById() so you can just stick the Button array into the ViewHolder along with anything else you want to reference.

Something like this is how you'd do it.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null){//if we haven't already created a view
        //inflate a new view
        View rowview = (HorizontalScrollView) inflater.inflate(
        R.layout.hrowlayout, parent, false);
        LinearLayout ll1 = (LinearLayout) rowview.findViewById(R.id.ll);

        Button[] b = new Button[M];     

        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            b[i] = new Button(ll1.getContext());
            b[i].setText(....);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( x, 90);
            b[i].setLayoutParams(param2);
            ll1.addView(b[i],params2);
        }

        convertView = rowview;
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.buttons = b;
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    holder = convertView.getTag()
    for(Button button : holder.buttons){
        //do something
    }


    return convertView;   
}
```

and the View Holder

```
class ViewHolder{
    Button [] buttons;
    //other things
}
```

Comment: thank you it worked, one more question on this i want to change the color of the text on focus and i was doing like this 
    
    final int z = i;
              b[i].setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){
            @Override
               public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus){
             if(hasFocus){
              b[z].setTextColor(0xff7BCFFC);
             }
             else
              b[z].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
           } ); 

but the focus is staying on more than one button after using view group.

Comment: I'm not sure, perhaps opening a new question for this issue would be better than trying to answer here. Though 1 thing off the top of my head is are you setting the text color back in the getView() method. It;s possible the focus has changed but the color one the previous view hasn't been set back to the original color.

Comment: yes i am setting inside getView() method, as posted earlier in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476179/android-dynamic-listview-focus-returning-to-first-item-every-time-after-loosing   
 
initially i tried to set text color using b[i].setTextColor(R.drawable.textcol); but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

you can declear  your button array in viewholder itself

```
public static class viewHolder{
    Button[] b;
}
```

in `getView` you can use `holder.b=new Button[4];`