# Android: to get focus on child in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I am using 4 listview's of which last ListView is created as posted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712217/how-to-tag-button-to-viewholder-created-in-custom-adapter/16712424?noredirect=1#comment24067206_16712424), which has

```
HorizontalScrollView
---> LinearLayout
     ---> Buttons
```

Problem facing : I am using key events to control navigation from 1st listview to 4th listview, but the focus unexpectedly going to 4th ListView after 1st listview, so i used

```
list4.setItemsCanFocus(false);
```

and setting it back to true when right key is pressed when focus is in listview3, the whole item is getting focused but i want only the first button inside the linear layout to take focus...... Thank you